# Make parts of NSTextView unselectable

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to exclude parts of an NSTextView from selection instead of globally disabling/enabling it?

A custom attribute of `NSAttributedString` would be ideal if possible.

Comment: Is delegate method `textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:` what you're looking for?

Comment: I suppose it would work if custom logic is implemented, but I was hoping for a more straightforward out-of-the-box way.